# JQUERY: populating select box with optiongroup using json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am not sure what is wrong with my code, I have a couple of select boxes with class `categories` and I am populating the options with a json object.

here's my json file

```
[{
  "Apparel": [{
    "val": "Footwear",
   "text": "Footwear"
  }, {
   "val": "Lights",
   "text": "Lights"
  }, {
   "val": "Accessories",
   "text": "Accessories"
  }],

  "Automotive Parts": [{
    "val": "Hydraulic Parts",
    "text": "Hydraulic Parts"
   }, {
    "val": "Plastic Parts",
    "text": "Plastic Parts"
   }],
}]
```

here's my jquery code.

```
$.getJSON("json/categories.json", function(json) {
    $.each(json,function (i,optgroups){
      $.each(optgroups, function(groupName, options) {
        var $optgroup = $("<optgroup>", {
                label: groupName
        });

        $optgroup.appendTo('.categories');

        $.each(options, function(j, option) {
                var $option = $("<option>", {
                    text: option.text,
                    value: option.val
                });
                $option.appendTo($optgroup);
            });
      });
    });
});
```

the select box has a couple of options and each set of options falls under an optiongroup.

the problem is the optiongroup labels are only populated and not the options.

Comment: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc257ps7/) Seems to work for me

Comment: try to add another select box  with class `categories` . Please check this fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/yc257ps7/1/

Comment: Move **$optgroup.appendTo('.categories');** after the second "each" loop and should work.
https://jsfiddle.net/yc257ps7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move **$optgroup.appendTo('.categories');** after the second "*each*" loop and should work.